# How do I set a color for each point in a graph depending on a value

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I want to create a graph using matplotlib. This graph contains multiple plots for a wavenumber over a frequency. Now I want to use colors as an additional information for each point in the graph. Can I do that in Python? Can I specify the color as a list instead of `color='k'` for black e.g.? Where I have to calculate a color beforehand? Or is there another way?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried plt.scatter() ?
It enables you to define a color for each point. Here is an example :

```
pyplot.scatter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2.4, 4.2, 5.6, 8.2],
           c = ['cyan', 'skyblue', 'blue', 'navy', 'black'],
           s = [110, 90, 70, 50, 30],
           marker = 'o', edgecolors = 'none')
```

Here is the doc : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Comment: Thanks dude, im gonna try that